# And Where is not working before where condition?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Here I am overriding the `find()` method

```
class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord{
    public static function find() {
        return parent::find()
           ->where(['=',static::tableName().'.company_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id])
           ->andWhere(['=',static::tableName().'.branch_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id]);
    }
}
```

Now if I use the condition like this

```
\common\models\Order::find()->where(['stastus'=>'3'])->count();
```

the Active Record global condition is executed before the condition I am
using in Order model and after that the Order Model where overriding
the active record global condition.

And if I use the Active Record condition like this

```
class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord{
    public static function find() {
        return parent::find()
           ->andWhere(['=',static::tableName().'.company_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id])
           ->andWhere(['=',static::tableName().'.branch_id',Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id]);
    }
}
```

There were in my local model overriding the global condition. Difficult for
me to override each where with and where.

Comment: Some thing is tricky here..?

Comment: `\common\models\Order::find()->where(['stastus'=>'3'])->count(); ` raw sql please

Comment: i am in office at the moment will reply once i reach home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `where` and `andWhere` to `onCondition` in your `BaseActiveRecord` which I suppose is an alias for **`\yii\db\ActiveRecord`** as the `parent::find()` return object of `ActiveQuery` if you look into the `find()` method it returns below line

**`\yii\db\ActiveRecord`**

```
 return Yii::createObject(ActiveQuery::className(), [get_called_class()]);
```

you can see here [**`customizing-query-class`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#customizing-query-classes) to add an extra condition

```
class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord{
    return parent::find ()
            ->onCondition ( [ 'and' ,
                [ '=' , static::tableName () . '.application_id' , 1 ] ,
                [ '=' , static::tableName () . '.branch_id' , 2 ]
    ] );
}
```

Now if you call

```
\common\models\Order::find()->where(['status'=>'3'])->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

it will generate the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `order` 
   WHERE (`status` = 3) 
   AND 
   ((`order`.`application_id` = 1) AND (`order`.`branch_id` = 2))
```

Comment: i could not quiet get what you are trying to say @Sajid , i hope the solution  worked for you if you have another question you can create a new one

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how the Yii2 `ActiveRecord` works. When you call method `where()` it reset conditions, even if was not empty and when you call `andWhere()` it add new condition to existing ones.